# How to get list of all applications currently running and visible in Dock for Mac OS X programming?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I need to know which applications are running and have an active window. Something similar must be what's in the 'command + tab' hotkey switcher.

When I run some code like this:

```
NSWorkspace * ws = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
NSArray * apps = [ws runningApplications];
NSLog (@"%@", apps);
```

I get this in my log:

```
"<NSRunningApplication: 0x6080001052b0 (com.apple.loginwindow - 66)>",
"<NSRunningApplication: 0x608000105340 (com.apple.systemuiserver - 285)>",
"<NSRunningApplication: 0x6080001053d0 (com.apple.dock - 284)>",
"<NSRunningApplication: 0x608000105460 (com.apple.finder - 286)>",
"<NSRunningApplication: 0x6080001054f0 (com.apple.iTunesHelper - 339)>",
"<NSRunningApplication: 0x608000105580 (cc.omh.Clyppan - 340)>",
"<NSRunningApplication: 0x608000105610 (ws.agile.1PasswordAgent - 333)>",
"<NSRunningApplication: 0x6080001056a0 (com.irradiatedsoftware.Cinch-Direct - 342)>",
"<NSRunningApplication: 0x608000105730 (com.leapmotion.Leap-Motion - 343)>",
"<NSRunningApplication: 0x6080001057c0 (com.apple.notificationcenterui - 316)>",
"<NSRunningApplication: 0x608000105850 (com.smileonmymac.textexpander - 348)>",
"<NSRunningApplication: 0x6080001058e0 (com.lightheadsw.caffeine - 350)>",
"<NSRunningApplication: 0x608000105970 (2BUA8C4S2C.com.agilebits.onepassword4-helper - 309)>"
```

It's showing all running applications. I only want the applications that are running and visible in the Dock.

Comment: This is a good question now.

Answer (score 20):

The members of the array returned by `[NSWorkspace runningApplications]` are of type `NSRunningApplication`.  You want to pick out the ones whose `activationPolicy` property has type `NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular`.

Answer (score 9):

The following code uses the [NSWorkplace](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace) `workspace.runningApplications.filter` call to extract the applications.

```
// Swift 4.1
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa

let workspace = NSWorkspace.shared
let apps = workspace.runningApplications.filter{  $0.activationPolicy == .regular }
```

Comment: This is way too simple and easy to read :-)

Answer (score 8):

**Updated for Swift 3**

```
    let ws = NSWorkspace.shared()
    let apps = ws.runningApplications
    for currentApp in apps
    {
        if(currentApp.activationPolicy == .regular){
            print(currentApp.localizedName!)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To access the list of all running applications, use the `runningApplications` method in `NSWorkspace`.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working here. Thanks for the help!

```
NSWorkspace * ws = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
NSArray * apps = [ws runningApplications];

NSUInteger count = [apps count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    NSRunningApplication *app = [apps objectAtIndex: i];
    //NSLog (@"%@", app.bundleIdentifier );

    if(app.activationPolicy == NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular) {
       //NSLog(@"0"); These are the ones we want.
    }
}
```

Comment: The value of `NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular` happens to be 0, but it's a bad programming practice to write 0 when you mean `NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular`.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift. Write below code you will get all the running application names.

```
let ws = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()

let apps = ws.runningApplications

for currentApp in apps.enumerate(){        
    let runningApp = apps[currentApp.index]

    if(runningApp.activationPolicy == .Regular){
        print(runningApp.localizedName)        
    }
}
```

Comment: Changes for Swift 3:
for currentApp in apps.enumerated()
    {
        let runningApp = apps[currentApp.offset];
        
        if(runningApp.activationPolicy == .regular)
        {
            print(runningApp.localizedName);
        }
    }

Comment: it return's only the running application and what if i want other application which are visible in docks but not running(active)

Comment: This is quite odd: Why enumerate to get the index, only to get `runningApp`, when you already have `currentApp`? This is very roundabout.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated for optimal Swift 3**

`let workspace = NSWorkspace()`

`let apps = workspace.runningApplications.filter{$0.activationPolicy == NSApplicationActivationPolicy.regular}`

The apps array will contain every application that is currently running and on screen in view.